# Using Beautiful Soup to Find Links Before a Certain Letter

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I have a BeautifulSoup problem that hopefully you can help me out with.

Currently, I have a website with a lot of links on it. The links lead to pages that contain the data of that item that is linked. If you want to check it out, it's this one: http://ogle.astrouw.edu.pl/ogle4/ews/ews.html. What I ultimately want to accomplish is to print out the links of the data that are labeled with an 'N'. It may not be apparent at first, but if you look closely on the website, some of the data have 'N' after their Star No, and others do not. Afterwards, I use that link to download a file containing the information I need on that data. The website is very convenient because the download URLs only change a bit from data to data, so I only need to change a part of the URL, as you'll see in the code below.

I currently have accomplished the data downloading part. However, this is where you come in. Currently, I need to put in the identification number of the BLG event that I desire. (This will become apparent after you view the code below.) However, the website is consistently updating over time, and having to manually search for 'N' events takes up unnecessary time. I want the Python code to be able to do it for me. My original thoughts on the subject were that I could have BeautifulSoup search through the text for all N's, but I ran into some issues on accomplishing that. I feel like I am not familiar enough with BeautifulSoup to get done what I wish to get done. Some help would be appreciated.

The code I have currently is below. I have put in a range of BLG events that have the 'N' label as an example.

```
#Retrieve .gz files from URLs

from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Access website
URL = 'http://ogle.astrouw.edu.pl/ogle4/ews/ews.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(URL))

#Select the desired data numbers 
numbers = list(range(974,998)) 
x=0
for i in numbers:
    numbers[x] = str(i)
    x += 1
print(numbers)

#Get all links and put into list
allLinks = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    list_links = link.get('href')
    allLinks.append(list_links)

#Remove None datatypes from link list
while None in allLinks:
    allLinks.remove(None)
#print(allLinks)

#Remove all links but links to data pages and gets rid of the '.html'
list_Bindices = [i for i, s in enumerate(allLinks) if 'b' in s]
print(list_Bindices)
bLinks = []
for x in list_Bindices:
    bLinks.append(allLinks[x])
bLinks = [s.replace('.html', '') for s in bLinks]
#print(bLinks)

#Create a list of indices for accessing those pages
list_Nindices = []
for x in numbers:
    list_Nindices.append([i for i, s in enumerate(bLinks) if x in s])
#print(type(list_Nindices))
#print(list_Nindices)

nindices_corrected = []
place = 0
while place < (len(list_Nindices)):
    a = list_Nindices[place]
    nindices_corrected.append(a[0])
    place = place + 1
#print(nindices_corrected)

#Get the page names (without the .html) from the indices
nLinks = []
for x in nindices_corrected:
    nLinks.append(bLinks[x])
#print(nLinks)

#Form the URLs for those pages
final_URLs = []
for x in nLinks:
    y = "ftp://ftp.astrouw.edu.pl/ogle/ogle4/ews/2017/"+ x + "/phot.dat"
    final_URLs.append(y)
#print(final_URLs)
#Retrieve the data from the URLs
z = 0
for x in final_URLs:
    name = nLinks[z] + ".dat"
    #print(name)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(x, name)
    z += 1
#hrm = urllib.request.urlretrieve("ftp://ftp.astrouw.edu.pl/ogle/ogle4/ews/2017/blg-0974.tar.gz", "practice.gz")
```

This piece of code has taken me quite some time to write, as I am not a professional programmer, nor an expert in BeautifulSoup or URL manipulation in any way. In fact, I use MATLAB more than Python. As such, I tend to think in terms of MATLAB, which translates into less efficient Python code. However, efficiency is *not* what I am searching for in this problem. I can wait the extra five minutes for my code to finish if it means that I understand what is going on and can accomplish what I need to accomplish. Thank you for any help you can offer! I realize this is a fairly muti-faceted problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Access website
URL = 'http://ogle.astrouw.edu.pl/ogle4/ews/ews.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(URL), 'html5lib')
```

Here, I'm using the `html5lib` to parse the url content.

Next, we'll look through the table, extracting links if the star names have a `'N'` in them:

```
table = soup.find('table')

links = []
for tr in table.find_all('tr', {'class' : 'trow'}):
    td = tr.findChildren()
    if 'N' in td[4].text:
        links.append('http://ogle.astrouw.edu.pl/ogle4/ews/' + td[1].a['href'])


print(links)
```

Output:

```
['http://ogle.astrouw.edu.pl/ogle4/ews/blg-0974.html', 'http://ogle.astrouw.edu.pl/ogle4/ews/blg-0975.html', 'http://ogle.astrouw.edu.pl/ogle4/ews/blg-0976.html', 'http://ogle.astrouw.edu.pl/ogle4/ews/blg-0977.html', 'http://ogle.astrouw.edu.pl/ogle4/ews/blg-0978.html', 
...
]
```

Comment: That seems intuitive. However, I ran the code and got this error: "bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?"

Comment: @KykyElric I see. It seems you don't have html5lib. I recommend you install it... it's the only parser that seemed to work well the markup on that site. Here's a helpful link on installation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Comment: Installed and problem is solved. Thank you for such a simple and intuitive answer! You've saved me many headaches and hours wasted.

Comment: @KykyElric Glad it helped! Do consider marking my answer accepted if you wish, it helps the community :)

Comment: @COLDSPEED I do not see a way to mark it as accepted, otherwise I would have. I'm too used to MATLAB's help forums... How do I do it on StackOverflow? EDIT: I found it. Marked it!

Comment: @KykyElric Happy trails!